# Why does this returns true?

Tags: java

Java newbie here. I was struggling with this for a while and can't get why this happens. When I compare two integers with "==" it always returns true, even if they are not same. Here's an example:

```
    if (50/41 == 3/3){
        System.out.println("SAME");
    }else{
        System.out.println("NOT SAME");
    }
```

I appreciate any help and explanation.

Comment: Read about integer division.

Comment: In particular, what *integer* do you expect the result of 50/41 to be?

Comment: You're performing integer (whole number) arithmetic and comparing the results (which are integers). It's basically evaluating `(1 == 1)` which is true.

Comment: `if (50.0/41 == 3/3){` will not work, This'll be false

Comment: 50/41 = 1. 3/3 = 1. 1 == 1.

Comment: I thought everyone did integer division in primary school.  My son did it a year ago and he is 9.  Perhaps it's easily forgotten!?

Comment: Yup. It's my fault guys. I feel dumb now lol. Thanks for answers anyway. :(